# Having more than one prank at the same time

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, foundry

I'm trying to deploy a simple Lottery contract with the Foundry framework. While testing I had some little problem, in fact I defined the following modifier:

```
modifier selectedWinner() {
        vm.prank(ALICE);
        lottery.joinTheLottery{value: 1 ethereum}();
        vm.prank(BOB);
        lottery.joinTheLottery{value: 1 ethereum}();
        lottery.selectWinner();      
        _;
    }
```

I already tested the `selectWinner` and `joinTheLottery` function and they work.

My test should assert that the number of players at the moment is 2 (Alice and Bob):

```
function testNumberPlayers() public selectedWinner {
        uint256 n = lottery.getCurrentNumberOfPlayer();
        assertEq(n, 2);
```

but it trows an error. If I can guess, I'd say I can't can set up two `vm.prank()`. Am I right? Is there any solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While you want to set a signer for more that one transactions, you can use `vm.startPrank(bob)` and `vm.stopPrank`.

Like this

```
modifier selectedWinner() {
    vm.prank(ALICE);
    lottery.joinTheLottery{value: 1 ethereum}();
    vm.startPrank(BOB);
    lottery.joinTheLottery{value: 1 ethereum}();
    lottery.selectWinner();  
    vm.stopPrank();    
    _;
}
```